# Custom write for DataTime in JSON Serializer

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

How do I get a custom behavior in the JSON Serializer for DateTime?
My goal is to only serialize the year.

Here is my model:

```
case class Model(id: Option[Int], name: String, userID: String, date: DateTime, material: String, location: String, text: String, pathObject: Option[String], pathTexure: Option[String], pathThumbnail: Option[String])

object Model {
  implicit val tswrites: Writes[DateTime] = Writes { (dt: DateTime) => JsString(dt.year.get.toString) }

  implicit val modelWrites: Writes[Model] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Option[Int]] and
    (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "userId").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "date").write[DateTime] and
    (JsPath \ "material").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "location").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "text").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "f1").write[Option[String]] and
    (JsPath \ "f2").write[Option[String]] and
    (JsPath \ "f3").write[Option[String]])(unlift(models.Model.unapply))
}
```

The date field serializes as 631148400000

The desired date field serialization as 1990

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it,

Here is the solution:

```
object Model {

  implicit val tswrites: Writes[DateTime] = Writes { (dt: DateTime) => JsString(dt.year.get.toString) }

  implicit val modelWrites: Writes[Model] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Option[Int]] and
    (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "userId").write[String] and
    Writes.at[DateTime]((JsPath \ "date"))(tswrites) and
    (JsPath \ "material").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "location").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "text").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "f1").write[Option[String]] and
    (JsPath \ "f2").write[Option[String]] and
    (JsPath \ "f3").write[Option[String]])(unlift(models.Model.unapply))

}
```